# AsyncCommand в MVVM и обработка исключений

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

Изучаю асинхронное программирование и готовлю класс асинхронной команды для внедрения в свои проекты.

Поставил себе требования:

- Реализация для `WPF` на базе `.NET Core 3.1` с использованием `Binding` в кнопках или всякого рода меню
- Решение, не требующее сильно изменять существующий код проекта при внедрении класса в код при условии, что сейчас используется обычный синхронный `RelayCommand`
- Должен быть кастомный обработчик исключений, умеющий по-разному реагировать на разные типы исключений (как это обычно бывает в коде здорового человека)
- `CanExecute` должен возвращать `false` во время выполнения команды, и контрол должен немедленно на его изменения реагировать. Запретить команде одновременно выполняться несколько раз.
- Всё это должно работать, даже если я вызываю команду императивно, из любого (не UI) потока.

Использовал референсы:

- класс [`RelayCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) из гайда
- вот [этот блог пост](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/) для `ASP.NET`, где очень не любят `async void` (и наверное правильно делают)
- вот [этот очень сложный гайд](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands), во всяком случае для меня

И вот что получилось:

**AsyncRelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object param);
}

public class AsyncRelayCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<object, Task> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<Exception> _exceptionCallback;
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    // делаю обязательным добавление коллбэка обработчика исключений
    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback) : this(execute, null, exceptionCallback) { }
    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute, Action<Exception> exceptionCallback)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _exceptionCallback = exceptionCallback;
        _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        // говорят, инвок в диспетчер "дорогой", и лучше его делать только когда надо
        if (_dispatcher.CheckAccess()) 
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            _dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object param) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute == null || _canExecute(param));

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object param)
    {
        if (CanExecute(param))
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                await _execute(param);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // хочу вызывать обработчик исключений в UI потоке
                // быть может здесь будет лучше делать обычный синхронный инвок?
                await _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(_exceptionCallback, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object param) => _ = ExecuteAsync(param); // fire-and-forget
}
```

Писал я это все в рамках тестового **MVVM** проека, который выглядит вот так:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        <Button Margin="5" Content="Execute" Command="{Binding MyAsyncCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text = "some text";
    private IAsyncCommand _myAsyncCommand;

    // обработчик исключений
    private readonly Action<Exception> _exceptionCallback = new Action<Exception>(e => {
        try
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
        {
            // обрабатываю сгенерированное исключение
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // это должно ронять программу, и не теряться глубоко в асинхронных тасках
            // и оно работает (но это не точно)
            throw ex; 
        }
    });

    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public IAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand => _myAsyncCommand ?? (_myAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(async param => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) // типа долго выполняемая асинхронная команда...
        {
            Text = "Count: " + i.ToString(); // ...которая модифицирует какие-то свойства VM
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        int x = 0;
        x = 1 / x; // генерирую DivideByZeroException для теста обработчика исключений
    }, _exceptionCallback));

    public MainViewModel()
    {  
    }

    public void Start() // вызывается из переопределенного OnStartup()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            await MyAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync(null); // вызов команды из "любого" потока
        });
    }

    public void ShutDown() // OnExit()
    {
    }
}
```

Всё выше показанное **работает исправно**, но я прошу помочь с пониманием того, что я понаписал и ответить на следующие вопросы:

- Не ломаю ли я **MVVM**?
- Правильно ли я обрабатываю исключения, или меня надо бить палкой и всё переписывать?
- Правильно ли в классе команды я взаимодействую с `CommandManager` через диспетчер?
- Быть может есть еще что улучшить?

Comment: "Запретить команде одновременно выполняться несколько раз." - а вот захотите вы сделать кнопку вида "старт/стоп" и не мудрить с подменой текущей команды и это правило будет мешать. Ну и wpf любит проглатывать исключения, так что ваш throw ex; (разве не throw?) может уйти в никуда

Comment: Я вам уже говорил вроде что ломает MVVM - `<local:MainViewModel/>`. По поводу `try/catch` - их лучше вообще стараться не использовать, научитесь писать приложение так, чтоб у вас было как можно меньше обработчиков ошибок. Сам `AsyncRelayCommand` мне лично не понятен, что мешает использовать обычную команду, которая выполнит задачу асинхронно? Сейчас вы нагородили всякими `try/catch`, что мне кажется показывает на нарушение вашей архитектуры приложения.

Comment: @vitidev правильно, но я не использую команды для выполения чего-то супермедленного, и готового упасть или задедлочиться. Для этого у меня есть исполнитель в отдельном потоке, который слушает `BlockingCollection`. Максимум переварить какие-то уже загруженные данные, не более чем за пару секунд, поэтому возможность отмены выполения команды для меня излишняя. Спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я услышал, спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ запостил ответом то, что из этого всего вышло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы этим физически не можете сломать MVVM, т. к. MVVM не указывает на синхронность/асинхронность команд.
2. Нет. Я предпочёл бы как-то так:

```cs
if (ex is SomeException someEx)
{
    // handle someEx
}
else if (ex is OtherException)
{
    // ...
}
```

3. Я бы не советовал вызывать *любую* задачу в UI-потоке. Дайте возможность выбора "метода создания" задачи, например, планировщик задач (вы можете создать [свой планировщик](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netcore-3.1) для UI-потока).
4. Тут есть несколько ошибок проектирования:

   1. Вы можете создать `private` св-во `Dispatcher` вместо того, чтобы создавать отдельное поле `_dispatcher`.
   2. Вместо callback'а `_execute` типа `Func<object, Task>`, возьмите callback `Action<object>` и просто сделайте его асинхронным (это хорошо комбинируется с пунктом №3).
   3. Уберите этот `_exceptionCallback`. Если вы захотите обработать ошибку, просто используйте [`ContinueWith`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netcore-3.1) (для подобного он и был создан).
   4. `ShutDown` -> `Shutdown` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown?view=netcore-3.1)).
   5. Пишите имена параметров полностью (`param` -> `parameter`). Это повысит читаемость кода, а IntelliSence всё равно подскажет вам нужное имя.
   6. `Func<object, bool>` -> `Predicate<object>`

---

Код `Task`'а:

```cs
public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    readonly Action<object> callback;
    readonly Predicate<object> validator;
    readonly CancellationToken token;
    readonly TaskCreationOptions options;

    public AsyncCommand(/*...*/)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => validator(parameter);
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (!CanExecute(parameter))
            throw new ArgumentException("This command can not be executed", "parameter");

        return await new Task(s => callback(s), parameter, token, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Прошелся по реализации всех рекомендаций: п.2 сделал через `switch` с паттерн-матчингом. Стало реально лучше. п.3 разбираюсь, но я пока не понял, чем это лучше в моем случае, чем просто отдать делегат диспетчеру. Есть ли смысл? п.4.2 и 4.3 не смог пока разобраться, как с лямбдами `async (parameter) => { ... }`, не переписывая код VM под именованные функции сделать. Покажите "просто сделайте его асинхронным" и `ContinueWith`, пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot Часть1. Это вам кажется, что зачем пункт 3. Я сам часто как в своей практике, так и в практике др. программистов, которые не парились по поводу *расширяемости* кода, а потом либо делали значительные корректировки, либо переписывали код. Лишь немногие могут неоч кода сделать говнокод и управлять им, несмотря на то, то 300к строк уже настрочено. Чтобы не допустить такого и делать классы по-настоящему *расширяемыми*, нужны вот такие меры

Comment: @aepot Часть 2. Пунктом 4.2 и 4.3:
```c#
public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    readonly Action<object> callback;
    readonly Predicate<object> validator;
    readonly CancellationToken token;
    readonly TaskCreationOptions options;

    public AsyncCommand(/*...*/)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public async Task CanExecute(object parameter) => validator(parameter);
    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (!CanExecute(parameter)) throw;

        return await new Task(s => callback(s), parameter, token, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне сказали, что редактировать коммент можно только через 5 минут (тупил долго)

Comment: И всё равно затупил с `CanExecute`))

Comment: То что вы предложили, работает, но я вот что подумал: если сделать просто Action, то сам делегат не будет асинхронным (либо `async void`, что не есть гуд), а в синхронном нельзя будет использовать асинхронные плюшки. Есть ли смысл избавляться от асинхронности у `execute` делегага таким образом, чтобы потом снова внутри него ее добиваться?

Comment: спасибо вам! Я опубликовал в соседнем ответе итоговый результат.

Answer (score 3):

Для истории оставлю здесь то, что получилось в итоге.

- Я отказался от обработчика исключений, при синхронных тасках он был не нужен, и здесь, хорошо подумав, я решил, что это излишество.
- Теперь использую синхронный делегат для `ExecuteAsync`, при этом сам делегат работает внутри `Task`.
- Необработанные исключения теперь выскакивают в коде там, где они случились, что намного упростит отладку. Но у меня и не бывает особо команд, где могут непредсказуемо выскакивать исключения.

В общем, оттолкнулся от первоначальной задачи - сделать так, чтобы код комманд не подмораживал интерфейс и нельзя было запустить комманду повторно, пока она исполняется.

**Финальное решение**

```csharp
public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
{
    Task ExecuteAsync(object param);
}

public class AsyncRelayCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    private Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    }

    private void InvalidateRequerySuggested()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
        else
            Dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => !_isExecuting && (_canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter));

    public async Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                Task task = new Task(s => _execute(s), parameter);
                task.Start();
                await task;
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
                InvalidateRequerySuggested();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _ = ExecuteAsync(parameter);
}
```

**Использование**

```csharp
private IAsyncCommand _myAsyncCommand;

public IAsyncCommand MyAsyncCommand => _myAsyncCommand ?? (_myAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i ++)
    {
        Text = "Count: " + i.ToString();
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}));
```

Да, обычный `Thread.Sleep()` теперь не вызывает никаких лагов.

Главное достоинство такого подхода в том, что в моих проектах код командных делегатов VM не придется переписывать вообще. Так же, решение получилось расширяемым, при желании к конструктору таска можно прикрутить CTS и `TaskScheduler`.

Спасибо всем за помощь!